# Long tag name pops out of the tag card in the tags page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, design, user-interface

The name of a tag overflows on the right of its card in the [tags page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags?page=27&tab=popular) if it is very long.

For instance, the tag [mr-tonegawa-middle-management-blues](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mr-tonegawa-middle-management-blues):

> [image]

**Browser:** Brave. Version 1.24.85 Chromium: 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (x86_64)
**OS:** macOS Catalina. Version 10.15.7

Comment: while i don't get the tag to overflow like that i do have the tag edit link overflow - https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1MVC.jpg

Comment: @Memor-X Ohh, I see. How do you have an edit link directly on the tag card, though? Does it appear when you cross the 20k reputation threshold, perhaps?

Comment: Just putting here that this is highly possibly related to [the global switching to system font based on OS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/241919) (I believe Memor-X is using Windows, which is what I also use and see)

Comment: We changed the status to status-deferred and sent the ticket to Public Platform as part of bug duty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this issue (Chrome). Unfortunately the Brave browser is [not officially supported](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/) on the network, so if this is a rendering issue specific to that browser, we can’t spend more time on this.